# How to set axis units in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, units-of-measurement

I'm trying to generate some schematic figures using gnuplot. My x scale is of angstrom and the y scale if of mV. Currently, I have the x scale goes like:

```
0 1e-9 2e-9 3e-9 etc.
```

And my y scale goes like

```
-0.07 -0.06 -0.05 etc.
```

And I want them to be

```
0 10 20 30 etc.
-70.0 -60.0 -50.0 etc.
```

respectively. 
Is there a way to do this from within the gnuplot (apart from setting the xrange an yrange parameters and multiplying the values by the appropriate amounts)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of:

1. You could make use of `set xtics` (see documentation [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-29800043.89))
   Then you can explicitly specify what value on your axis will receive which label. So something like this:

   ```
   set xtics ("0" 0, "10" 1e-9, "20" 2e-9, ...)
   ```

   should work. Proceed accordingly with the y axis (`set ytics`)
2. You could multiply your values accordingly. (Like what you have mentioned in your question)

   ```
   plot "Data.dat" u ($1*1e9):($2*1e2)
   ```